# Throw custom exception in spring boot with an Autowired variable

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, exception, autowired

A custom exception that requires the use of an `Autowired` variable

```
// @Component // should be a component to use autowire variable
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class MyException extends Exception {

    // This should be commented in
    // @Autowired
    // public RequestModel reqModel;

    // public MyException(ExceptionType type) {
    public MyException(ExceptionType type, RequestModel reqModel) {
        super();
        switch type {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the rest controllers and interceptors we throw the error

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    // These should be commented out
    @Autowired
    public RequestModel reqModel;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // This should be thrown without adding the reqModel as a param
        // Unsure how to throw this without using "new"
        throw new MyException.MyException(PARAM_MISSING, reqModel);
    }
}
```

I understand that instantiating a class using `new` will null the `Autowired` variables. When I tried dropping the `new` and converting the `MyException` class to a `@Component`, I see issues with calling the `MyException` class constructor.

What is the best way to implement a custom exception in springboot using an autowired variable?

Comment: You should do no such thing. Why not just pass the information from RequestModel that the exception needs?

Comment: Yeah, like Strelok says this is not really a sensible way to do things. It is you who are throwing the exception, not spring, so you need to construct the object and therefore the spring application context doesn't know anything about it. Passing the required information into the constructor is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I've been passing in `RequestModel` and it works. I was hoping for a more robust way to do this. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Strelok bump . . .